# reading body of tag inside a react function

Tags: reactjs

I've made this component MButton with text **Submit** as content of the tag

```
<MButton value={"Go"} color={"primary"} onChange={onChange} fullWidth={true}>Submit</MButton>
```

I need to access the content (text **Submit**) of it. Below is the code for MButton, I don't want from params, I can access 'value' param and write '**Submit**' instead of '**Go**'.

```
function MButton(params) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Button
      fullWidth={params.fullWidth}
      variant="contained"
      color={params.color}
      className={classes.button}
      onChange={params.onChange}
    >
      //Submit from above
    </Button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `children` prop:

```
function MButton(params) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Button
      fullWidth={params.fullWidth}
      variant="contained"
      color={params.color}
      className={classes.button}
      onChange={params.onChange}
    >
      {params.children}
    </Button>
  );
}
```

`params.children` returns everything within starting and ending tags of specific element. Please read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html).